# How to split the App Insights table data to multiple datasets

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I have Application sights table with around million rows and want equal split data  4 datasets /queries and then merge them all in report. I have the insertDate which can be used to partition to different datasets without overlap of data between the queries. using  insertDate>=ago(180d) and insertDate < ago(180d) will give me only 2 partitions of this data , how can i split this data equally ,lets say 5 datasets meaning 5 queries each of which returns 2 months data?

Note I don't know the underlying dates so cannot hard code dates like    between dates operator .  This is sample data , some months have more data than other months but need to split the data equally to avoid the app insights rest API's max rows limit of 500K rows

*Context*: Application Insights rest API connector to powerBI does not support more than 500K rows so above is one workaround I am thinking of.

```
let T = datatable(release:string, insertDate:datetime )  
[
"2205", datetime(2022-01-05),
"2205", datetime(2022-01-10),
"2205", datetime(2022-02-10),
"2204", datetime(2022-03-25),
"2203", datetime(2022-04-15),
"2205", datetime(2022-04-12),
"2205", datetime(2022-05-12),
"2206", datetime(2022-06-23),
"2207", datetime(2022-07-27),
"2209", datetime(2022-08-12),
"2201", datetime(2022-09-26),
"2201", datetime(2022-10-08),
];

T
|take 100;
```

Comment: What is your motivation for doing so?

Comment: How many records?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, app insights rest api connect to PBI cannot support more than 500K rows so trying to split the dataset to multiple datasets to union them later in the report.   row count is more than 700K and can increase to 1.2millon rows

Comment: Yet another [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Apologies David , updated the question with the context behind the approach i am trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let T = datatable(release:string, insertDate:datetime )  
[
"2205", datetime(2022-01-05),
"2205", datetime(2022-01-10),
"2205", datetime(2022-02-10),
"2204", datetime(2022-03-25),
"2203", datetime(2022-04-15),
"2205", datetime(2022-04-12),
"2205", datetime(2022-05-12),
"2206", datetime(2022-06-23),
"2207", datetime(2022-07-27),
"2209", datetime(2022-08-12),
"2201", datetime(2022-09-26),
"2201", datetime(2022-10-08),
];
let groups = 5;
let total_rows = toscalar(T | count);
let group_rows = 1.0 * total_rows / groups;
let edge_rows = toscalar
(
    range x from group_rows to total_rows - group_rows step group_rows
    | extend x = round(x)
    | summarize make_list(x)
);
union   (print insertDate = datetime(0001))
       ,(T
         | order by insertDate asc 
         | where row_number() in (edge_rows)
         | project insertDate
        )
| order by insertDate asc
| project fromDate  = insertDate
         ,toDate    = next(insertDate, 1, datetime(3000))
```

| fromDate | toDate |
| --- | --- |
| 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2022-01-10T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-01-10T00:00:00Z | 2022-04-12T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-04-12T00:00:00Z | 2022-05-12T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-05-12T00:00:00Z | 2022-08-12T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-08-12T00:00:00Z | 3000-01-01T00:00:00Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32Sz3LCIBDG75nJO%20x4gk7SEvxX7XjrI3jrdBw0W5s2AQfIaDs%20fDdqLDZVuMD%20vv2AZUv0MIcZ5MrTXJbILJaoHE6dt4VeJ1Boh9Y/K49TEqEvKgQOEEcvcdSTUgx7CbSASSFlKrJUDHlyA2fiBpYBHnRxP5Vn834XD9Ls1tmE5Q08DPCoi0ep7Ld43MXjVI5bPOnix8A86%20JJKkfXcSbIoMGvT3FU0q%20trak3jr5ueAp441W5sGbbBL1xK1Uqy%20awh5WptedhXivL7gXchZkPJ9%20TGPM1/rWMIxZHQMMqvUbYwZs1VWjrTeiYhsh53AT7o88ecOdR52Q1A2I6ZzveIldXlbLFN0KlPnFRFs4faPOcWhdGk4ptqFV90KnHhj5WTwiR8ZMdjYTNz%20vG39gcLSy/wmzlVnAh2r6jRbradqHraomWcZIDO1eHX6g31nzgKrzPLybl1TMb1OY2NT3E6Sn/%20UDizZE3Ck0FZL%20yBLKgffpUAc5/ABXEeC7pAwAA)

Comment: Thanks David. Can you please help me understand how this will help to select the data   dynamically like as I mentioned I dont know the underlying dates to mention in the where condition like  qeury1 = T| where insertDate between <00001-01-01> <2022-01-10> ? please correct if i am missing something here. .  Basically I should be able to select something   like  :  query1 | where <condition to get the first chuck of rows> = <> ; Query 2 | where  condition to get the second chuck of rows; etc

Comment: As you can see in the code, once you determined the groups number, the rest is completely dynamic. You get x ranges of dates and for each one of them you should generate a query like `T | where insertDate >= fromDate and insertDate < toDate`.